# Neo4j: Problems writing Java procedure (@Procedure is disallowed for this location)

Tags: java, neo4j, annotations, procedure, graph-databases

I am new to Java but am trying to write a simple Java procedure that executes some Cypher code.

First I tried to do it without a procedure. See following code. It works just fine and returns the number of nodes in my local database (Community Edition).

```
package neo4j.java.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Map;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Result;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class ExecuteCypher1 {
public static void main(String[] args){

    GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
    File dbpath = new File("C:/../JavaTestDB");
    GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabase(dbpath);

    String query = "match (n) return count(n)";

    Result result = db.execute( query );

    while ( result.hasNext() )
    {
        Map<String, Object> row = result.next();
        for ( String key : result.columns() )
        {
            System.out.printf( "%s = %s%n", key, row.get( key ) );
        }
    }
}
}
```

Then I tried to rewrte it as a procedure:

```
package neo4j.java.examples;

import java.util.Map;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Result;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Context;
import org.neo4j.procedure.Procedure;

public class ExecuteCypher2 {

    @Context
    public GraphDatabaseService db;

    @Procedure(name = "neo4j.java.countN")

    String query = "match (n) return count(n)";

    Result result = db.execute( query );

    while ( result.hasNext() )
    {
        Map<String, Object> row = result.next();
        for ( String key : result.columns() )
        {
            System.out.printf( "%s = %s%n", key, row.get( key ) );
        }
    }  
}
```

The problem I have is that `@Procedure` is marked, telling me that "The annotation @Procedure is disallowed for this location". Can anyone tell me where the mistake is? I imported `org.neo4j.procedure.Procedure;` and in the template example of neo4j (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/ - secion 6.1.3.3.) the `@Procedure` is at the same location as far as I see it.

Thank you

EDIT:
I read the documentation and know that wiriting neo4j-procedures is not that easy for java-beginners. However, I still want to try a simple example. I compiled the ([Neo4j procedure example](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template)) without errors but removed the `mode = WRITE` and the according imports for it to throw no errors. (The `import org.neo4j.procedure.PerformsWrites` was marked as "The type PerformsWrites is deprecated" and `import static org.neo4j.procedure.Procedure.Mode.WRITE` coudn't be resolved.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to java then you shouldn't probably start writing neo4j procedures. it's not exactly a good beginners exercise.

Please learn enough Java first before you embark in using specific APIs.

The annotation goes onto the method.

There is detailed documentation http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/
and an example project: https://github.com/neo4j-examples/neo4j-procedure-template

Comment: Thank you. I know its not very good for beginners but I still want to try as I might need to write neo4j proceudres in the near future.
What do you mean by "The annotation goes onto the method"?
I have read the documentation and got the example procedure template running (maybe more or less? / At least no error). Note: I removed the `mode = WRITE` and the according imports for it to run. The import `org.neo4j.procedure.PerformsWrites` was marked as "The type PerformsWrites is deprecated" and import static `org.neo4j.procedure.Procedure.Mode.WRITE` coudnt be resolved.. Any hints on that?

Answer (score 0):

You have not written a method to contain your code

```
public static void myMethod(){
{
    while ( result.hasNext() )
    {
        Map<String, Object> row = result.next();
        for ( String key : result.columns() )
        {
            System.out.printf( "%s = %s%n", key, row.get( key ) );
        }
    }
}
```

This is fundamental. Perhaps its worth doing some basic Java tutorials first.

Comment: Thank you. As you see I have this included in my first code which I run as a normal Java program. When I tried to write the procedure I tred to follow the example from the Neo4j page (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/) at the bottom. I want to call the Java Code from within Neo4j as a procedure. So I don't know if a method is needed in this case. I don't see a method in the Neo4j example... Or am I not seeing it? Maybe you can help me figureing it out. Thanks!

In the n the Neo4j Template

Comment: It is needed. Wrap it in a function and add the appropriate annotations and it should work. The example does have functions... The are called 'search' and 'index' respectively. The first one is  public Stream<SearchHit> search( @Name("label") String label,
                                     @Name("query") String query )

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I'll try it once I have time for it.